# Yeoman generator - deep copy empty folder structure

Tags: copy, directory, generator, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Given the following generator folder structure; I'm attempting to deep copy all folders under the 'for_copy' folder.

- generator root

  - app
  - templates

    - **for_copy**

      - data
      - external
      - media

All the folders are empty. I would like to have this structure created for me when I invoke the generator.

I have tried using fs.copy, bulkCopy, and [bulkDirectory](http://yeoman.github.io/generator/actions.html). None of them are doing the job.

Any clues as to how I might achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

See below code snippet:

```
writing: function() {
        this.log('Writing templates...');

        //doesn't work
        this.fs.copy(
            this.templatePath('for_copy'),
            this.destinationRoot()
            );

        //doesn't work
        this.bulkCopy(
            this.templatePath('for_copy'),
            this.destinationRoot()
            );

        //doesn't work
        this.bulkDirectory(
            this.templatePath('for_copy'),
            this.destinationRoot()
            );

        //doesn't work
        this.bulkDirectory(
            this.templatePath('for_copy') +'**/*',
            this.destinationRoot()
            );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeoman only cares about files. When you use `bulkDirectory`, you actually copy files over, not directories.

You can use [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) module to create directories.

```
mkdirp.sync(path.join(this.destinationPath(), 'data'));
mkdirp.sync(path.join(this.destinationPath(), 'external'));
// etc ...
```